# How can I timeout the value of a variable to null when it's not updated in a specific interval of time in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class with `set` and `get` methods like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Double variable = null;

    // set method
    public void setVariable(Double value){
        this.variable = value;
    }

    // get method
    public Double getVariable(){
        return this.variable;
    }
}
```

I'd like to make my `set` method in a way that it goes back to `null` if I don't update its value after a timeframe since it was settled. For example, let's say I create an instance of `MyClass` and use the method `setVarible(2.2)` inside it, if I don't update its value using the set method again inside 1 second I want it to go back to `null`. **Is there any standard way of solving a problem like this in Java? What approach should I use to solve it?**

---

Context:

I've thought of solving this problem declaring a global variable with a counter and always resetting the counter when the set method is run, but I got stuck because it would require asynchronous calls or threads for not stopping the main thread. Besides that, I didn't manage to make it work this way too and it seems like an overcomplicated solution to follow for a simple problem. I think the approach I'm trying to use is the wrong one to solve it.

Comment: You'll need some Thread that monitors the time and calls `setVariable(null)`. The timer can be reset if you call `setVariable()` yourself. I'm not aware of a standard method for this problem.

Comment: Do you actually need to null the reference when the timer times out? Set a single `long` with the current time stamp on set, and then when get is invoked test if it's still valid (and null the reference if it is expired at that time).

Comment: BTW, your class seems like a timed [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (and you might consider returning an `Optional` to make that clear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to set the field to null actively, as long as it looks like you did on the outside (assuming of course that all access to the field goes through the appropriate getter):

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final long VARIABLE_FRESHNESS_THRESHOLD = 1 * 1000l;

    private Double variable = null;
    private long variableUpdateMillis = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    public void setVariable(Double value){
        this.variable = value;
        this.variableUpdateMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public Double getVariable(){
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.variableUpdateMillis >= VARIABLE_FRESHNESS_THRESHOLD) {
          return null;
        }
        return this.variable;
    }
}
```

You can optimize that to avoid the `currentTimeMillis()` call if the last one already timed out (by setting the `variable` to null in the `return null` case and checking that first):

```
    public Double getVariable(){
        if (this.variable != null &&
            System.currentTimeMillis() - this.variableUpdateMillis >= VARIABLE_FRESHNESS_THRESHOLD) {
          this.variable = null;
        }
        return this.variable;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest changing `return null;` to `this.variable = null;` (why keep the previous value?).

Comment: Power of encapsulation FTW! :)

Comment: I aborted an answer which went in this vein. One addition: It does require that all accesses to the 'variable' are done via the getter. But with that note, yeah this is a fine way to do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I consider this an optimization and wanted to present the simplest possible way primarily, so that it's easier to understand. (Update: I've added the optimized version now)

Comment: This is incorrect unfortunately, albeit a decent solution in other situations. The question indicates that OP wants the variable to be set back to null within 1 second if not accessed again, not upon next reference to set or get. It's not good practice to allow for get functions to retrieve anything other than the variable they're referencing. This is valid solution if you change the name from getVariable to something else that indicates it's not a getter but rather performing some logic.

Comment: @Jason: I disagree. The state of an object is defined by the behaviour of its visible members. If the field is considered `private` and the method is `public` then setting the field and returning different values from the getters are equivalent. That's what encapsulation is all about.

Comment: That's an interesting take, i'll have to do some research, my knowledge could be limited on the subject.

Comment: Yeah so the issue I have with that getter is that it might be perfectly valid that you want to retrieve that member state in the future regardless if it has been 1 second since the last modification. If that is the case, now you have to create a getter with an unconventional name to retrieve the state. Wouldn't it make more sense to create a method that is still an accessor that doesn't follow the conventional naming pattern of a getter?

Comment: @Jason: it seems that much of your design sensibilities in comments to this question revolve about the idea of objects of essentially being "value holders" with some methods to manipulate that data. However, I'd posit that this is only one possible role that objects can hold (usually things like DTOs), but not all they could be. Objects can have a rich internal live only some of which is externally visible. Treating each class as if it is essentially just a Java Bean leaves a lot of possibilities on the table.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If an object can be immutable, it should be. In this case it is possible so it should be immutabe. The author asked how **should** this be done, not **how** it can be done. None of the other answers to this question are thread-safe so I provided a thread-safe solution.

Comment: @Jason Did I misunderstand something here? How can this object be immutable? The OP wants to set the variable to `null` at some point, i.e. mutating the object.

Comment: @Sweeper OP wants to know if **there is a standard way to solving this in java**, not how or when to set to **null**.

Comment: @Jason After reading your answer, I see your (valid) point now.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, I appreciate the validation.

Comment: @Jason: I don't agree that an object that has a different observable state after some time can ever be considered "immutable" even if the internal state doesn't change. Conversely, it's quite possible to have mutating internal state (for example: caching a hashCode) while still being immutable. If the *external, observable* state of an object can change, then most of the benefits of immutable objects are lost.

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in the comments, I would start by setting an `updateTime` field with the current time stamp; and I would `null` the `variable` in `get` if the value wasn't updated within the correct time frame. I would also make the class generic (limiting it to `Double` seems unwise to me). Further, I would take advantage of [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to indicate that this class returns an *optional* value. Putting that all together, it might look something like

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private T variable = null;

    private long updateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // set method
    public void setVariable(T value) {
        this.variable = value;
        updateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    // get method
    public Optional<T> getVariable() {
        if (variable != null && System.currentTimeMillis() - updateTime <= 1000) {
            return Optional.of(variable);
        }
        variable = null;
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should getVariable modify the internal state of the object? Is that conventional?

Comment: @Jason Normally no, but then I would argue OP's requirements are not conventional (*if I don't update its value using the set method again inside 1 second I want it to go back to null*); are you proposing using threads to reset that field? And **every** implementation that actually results in that field becoming `null` means the state of the class mutated.

Comment: In this particular case it might make more sense to query whether or not an update has been made, such that; isVariableFresh() and upon it returning true, return the actual variable. If it is not, simply throw an IllegalStateException upon accessing.

Comment: @Jason Or use `isPresent()` and access it like an `Optional` to begin with?

Comment: But the object is still unnecessarily mutable and the member would have to be defined of type Optional which IIRC is not conventional.

Answer (score 1):

What I would propose is the make the object immutable and only re-assign the object to a new state once value has changed. Similar to Guavas stopwatch, you can only get the internal state if its within a threshold. You have to do an initial check or catch the exception if it is not. This does not allow for null values and it is immutable, and the object is effectively thread-safe. It also allows you to provide a getter regardless of state if needed in the future.

You could make getIfInThreshold() throw IllegalStateException but it's not really necessary if you access it properly using isInThreshold().

```java
   public static class MyClass {

        private final Double variable;

        private final long lastAccessNanoseconds;

        private final TimeUnit thresholdUnit;

        private final long threshold;

        public MyClass(Double variable, long lastAccessNanoseconds, TimeUnit thresholdUnit, long threshold) {
            this.variable = Objects.requireNonNull(variable);
            this.lastAccessNanoseconds = lastAccessNanoseconds;
            this.thresholdUnit = thresholdUnit;
            this.threshold = threshold;
        }

        public MyClass(Double variable, TimeUnit thresholdUnit, long threshold) {
            this(variable, System.nanoTime(), thresholdUnit, threshold);
        }

        public static MyClass forSeconds(Double variable, long seconds) {
            return new MyClass(variable, TimeUnit.SECONDS, seconds);
        }

        public boolean isInThreshold() {
            return System.nanoTime() - lastAccessNanoseconds < TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(threshold, thresholdUnit);
        }

        public Double getIfInThreshold() {
            if (!isInThreshold()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not get variable, not within time threshold.");
            }
            return variable;
        }
    }
```

Example usage

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyClass myClass = MyClass.forSeconds(1.0, 1);

        Thread.sleep(2_000L);

        assert !myClass.isInThreshold();

        try {
            double value = myClass.getIfInThreshold();

            // cannot use value because of IllegalStateException
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Not accessible anymore!");
        }

        myClass = MyClass.forSeconds(.5, 1);

        Thread.sleep(500);

        double value = myClass.getIfInThreshold();
    }
```

Comment: I would not use `try...catch` to access it. Wouldn't checking `isInThreshold` a before accessing it a better approach? You wouldn't `try...catch` an array access to check if the index is out of bounds, would you?

Comment: The purpose of the try-catch is not to show the paradigm of how to use it, but rather how it can go wrong. In some cases you might not want to do 2 checks to see if it's within the threshold, calling getIfInThreshold() and catching the exception and then handling that exception would be 1 less check. It is also worth noting that in this example i don't need the try-catch the second time.

Comment: @Sweeper I have updated the example to not use the try-catch when not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach, basically store the last set and validate in the get method

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimeOutValue {

    private int TIME_OUT = 1000;

    private long lastSet = 0;

    private Double variable = null;

    // set method
    public void setVariable(Double value){
        lastSet = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        this.variable = value;
    }

    // get method
    public Double getVariable(){
        if(lastSet != 0l && Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - lastSet > TIME_OUT){
            this.variable = null;
            lastSet = 0l;
        }
        return this.variable;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        TimeOutValue test = new TimeOutValue();

        test.setVariable(1.1);
        System.out.println(test.getVariable());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(test.getVariable());
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println(test.getVariable());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The output for the test in main method

```
1.1
1.1
null
```